# PRAM and NVRAM differences and overlap with eachother and UEFI firmware chip

Tags: nvram

1. Is PRAM stored on the same NVRAM chip that non-PRAM variables are stored.  I always assumed that NVRAM was the UEFI firmware chip on the logic board. Are all of these one in the same (NVRAM - PRAM - UEFI firmware), basically are they all stored on the same chip?
2. How do you set the PRAM variables like you set the NVRAM variables with the nvram command.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, PRAM is stored on the same NVRAM chip as the firmware variables, but it is managed separately.  It actually shows up as a device in the firmware device tree.

[HT1242: What's stored in PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1242)

When you reset one, you reset the other.

[HT1379: Resetting your Mac's PRAM and NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)

AFAIK, Apple has never supported direct developer access to PRAM, so it is not documented well (or at all).  The functions `readXPRAM` and `writeXPRAM` can be used to access the raw bytes, although these days they are just wrappers around IOKIT functions which access the `APL,MacOS75` partition in NVRAM.

The `nvram` command line program only manipulates the firmware variables stored in NVRAM, and so does not let you access the PRAM partition.